# How to inspect whole pl/sql stack information from another session which holds locks and causes deadlock

Tags: oracle

I have a generated .trc trace file due deadlock error. The file contains everything I need about current session and it has cool pl/sql call stack. But how about all of this information for another session? Everything it has is simple sql which can be a part of a more comprehensive plsql code. Is it possible to retrieve the full plsql call stack for another session? Because for now I have no idea which piece of code from another session can cause such deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really cannot know what statement is *causing* a deadlock, only the session.  The guilty session may very well execute several dml statements before committing.  The actual guilty statement could have been earlier than the current statement, but only the current statement will be found in the v$ views.